# Как запустить проект в Genymotion

Tags: android, android-studio, genymotion

Установил Genymotion и плагин для Android Studio, нажимаю run на проект в итоге после нажатия "create AVD" выбивает стандартный эмулятор
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот мой Edit configurations
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Создать виртуальное устройство в `Genymotion`.
2. Запустить эмулятор `Genymotion` (через сам `Genymotion` или через плагин студии)
3. Запустить проект (`run`) - запущенный эмулятор `Genymotion` появится в списке выбора на каком устройстве запустить проект.

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению тоже самое. http://imgur.com/a/fCeSm

Comment: Выбрал "Show Device Chooser Dialog" в Edit Configurations, заработало! Спасибо за помощь)